# BrowserLink MVC 6 - Not Working - No Extra Code Injected

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, browser-link

How do I get BrowserLink to work in MVC6 - using RC1 Release 1. Using Visual Studio 2015 Update 1.

Browsers never appear in Browser Link dashboard. No extra js is injected or extra web calls made by site so it just seems to not be adding browser link code.

I have app.UseBrowserLink(). I am running in Development mode, debug. I have tried CoreClr and Full Framework. This happens even with a brand new Asp.net 5 web template with no changes made to it.

What else do I need to do? Does Browserlink actually work for anyone with ASP.NET 5 RC1?

I would also add I ran older projects based on MVC5 and Browserlink works on them without issue.

Comment: I guess the fact I am getting upvotes suggest other people are having issues? Can anyone confirm if it works for them in RC1?

Comment: I can confirm that it seems not to work out of the box on a brand new image/install.

Comment: @RayWomack: The answer given fixed it for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to be an issue with the installation of "Microsoft ASP.NET 5 RC1 Update 1". Go into Control Panel > Programs and Features > Click "Microsoft ASP.NET 5 RC1 Update 1" and press Change > Repair.

Fixed it for me on three of my development machines.

Comment: WOW! Fixed it on both my machines. Can't believe it. Good spot - thanks for the help.

Comment: This was driving me nuts. How did you figure this out?

Comment: @PaulTotzke Time, Just lots of time. haha